# Can we pass a conditional parameter in ExplicitWait expected condition?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[This is](https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/1331/) the website. What I'm trying to do is, click the button and get the text which show the IPAddress of your system.

I'm able to locate the element which is `<span>`but it shows the text once the get IP Address button clicked.

So my concern is can we use conditions in ExplicitWait ? for example

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("lblIPAddress")).getText().length()>0
```

This is conditional parameter which i want to use in ExplicitWait.

I'm using `textToBePresentInElement` method in Explicit wait but here I have to pass that string (`IP Address: 123.201.110.30`) hard coded.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(driver.findElement(By.id("lblIPAddress")), "IP Address: 123.201.110.30"));
```

Even though I am able to get the text by `invisibilityOf()` method of the loader , once it get hidden then it span shows the IPAddress text.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal12']"))));
System.out.println("IP address After wait = "+ driver.findElement(By.id("lblIPAddress")).getText());
```

But my query is to use condition in Explicit wait where it wait for the given time to check the condition (check weather text is available in the element or not).

This is the code :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/1331/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnGet")).click();
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("lblIPAddress")).getText().length());
    System.out.println("IP Address = "+ driver.findElement(By.id("lblIPAddress")).getText());       
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(driver.findElement(By.id("lblIPAddress")), "IP Address: 123.201.110.30"));
    System.out.println("IP address After wait = "+ driver.findElement(By.id("lblIPAddress")).getText());

}
```

Comment: Maybe try with: `ExpectedConditions.textMatches()` and in regex pattern parameters provide IP Address regex validation, then You extract content of element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use conditions in Explicit Wait (Expected Conditions) however, you can use any custom condition in FluentWait.

If you are using Java 8, you could write a function which takes condition and executes it.

for your case, you could write something like this.

```
@Test
public void testFluentWait(){

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("websubmit"));

    waitUntilElementHasText(element);

    //If you are using Java 8
    waitUntilCondition(() -> element.getAttribute("type").contains("submit"));

}

//Only if you are using Java 8
public boolean waitUntilCondition(Callable<Boolean> condition){

    Wait wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);


    wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                return condition.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return false;
}

public boolean waitUntilElementHasText(final WebElement element){

    Wait wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);


    wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return element.getText().length() > 0;
        }
    });

    return element.getText().length() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this code. It returns the `false` can you try at your end ?

Comment: the example I have given is working. could you check that.

Comment: come on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149791/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-45232461-can-we-pass-a-conditional-parameter

Comment: tested on the website you have mentioned with this condition and it works perfectly fine. `waitUntilElementHasText(driver.findElement(By.id("lblIPAddress")));`

Comment: I don't know what happening at my end i'm getting result as false all time. is there any issue with imports. i've imported the package can u see on chat i have posted the whole program

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExpectedConditions` to handle this very simply. `.textToBePresentInElementLocated()` is a partial text match and can be used to wait for the IP to appear. Once it appears, you can fetch it using `.getText()` on the element. Code below is working and outputs "IP Address: x.x.x.x".

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btnGet")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("lblIPAddress"), "IP Address:"));
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("lblIPAddress")).getText());
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want to pass even a single character.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late to answer this, but I tried it by following method

public class TestFluentWait {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/1331/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnGet")).click();
    
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);        
    WebElement ele = wait.until( new Function<WebDriver,WebElement>()
            {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver)
                    {
                        WebElement reElement= driver.findElement(By.id("lblIPAddress"));
                        if(reElement.getText().length()>0)
                            return reElement;
                        else
                            return null;
                    }
            }
        );
    System.out.println("Text Is:"+ele.getText());
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

It works with FluentWait as well.

```
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).
            ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```