# Wait for a webelement to appear and keep clicking until that element appears

Tags: selenium, wait

I am stuck in a peculiar logic.
My requirements are as follows

1. Save the information
2. Click on Refresh button
3. Wait for inquiry id to appear
4. If(3) is not true wait for 10 seconds and trigger Step(2) again
   Keep 4 in loop unless the inquiry id appears

The inquiry id is of six digits so i am using

```
WebElement getInquiryId=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'^\d{6}$')]"));
```

Please help me out in framing the selenium code based on following requirements

Comment: Can you add the html code for the inquiry id element?

Comment: Refer This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232461/can-we-pass-a-conditional-parameter-in-explicitwait-expected-condition

Comment: Wouldn't saving the information invite a Refresh by default? Next we can wait for 10 seconds for the inquiry id to disappear in a loop. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would somehow be your code for Step 4:

```
while(!getInquiryId.isDisplayed()){
  try {
    Thread.sleep(10000); //wait for 10 seconds
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  if(getInquiryId.isDisplayed()){
    break;
  }else{
    refreshButton.click();
  }
}
```